# Remove a standard object from global search results

Tags: liveagent

I am trying to hide results from global search for a standard object (live Chat Transcript) for a profile of users. I have to give them Read access to this object in order for the chat to work, however I don't want them to be able to search records for this object from global search (not even the ones they own).

Can anyone suggest something that could work ?

Thanks
-Amit

Comment: Can you set the Org wide default for the object? Would setting it to private work for you?

Comment: try hiding the tab of that custom object in the user profile, if you have created a tab.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the visibility to the Tab in their profile.

Comment: Hi PepeFloyd, I tried removing access to "Live Agent Transcript" tab, but that didn't work. I think we can stop the users from being able to search for records only on custom object (by not creating a tab for the custom object). In this case we already have a  tab built out of the box.